# Is AutoIT specific to browser version

Tags: autoit

I'm trying to upload a file using AutoIT, It is working fine, but when i upgraded the Firefox Version to version 23.0, the AutoIT script is not working. The below code is working fine in Firefox Version 21. Don't know why it is. Any suggestions on this.

```
$windowHandle = WinGetHandle("File Upload")
WinActivate($windowHandle);
Send("C:\Test\Penguins.jpg")
ControlClick($windowHandle, "", "[CLASS:Button; TEXT:&Open]")
```

This is very simple file upload, but the file is not getting uploaded in Firefox version 23.0 Please let me know whether the AutoIT script is specific to browser.

Thanks in Advance

shiva

Comment: How do you upload the file with Firefox? Are you using an addon?

Comment: @mrt: I'm using selenium Webdriver with Java. but really i'm not aware of with AutoIT dependency...

Comment: Use some consoleWrite(s) to see which command fails.

Comment: @Xenobiologist: Thanks for your message, I used consoleWrite() on each and every line. at the first consoleWrite() before $windowHandle it is printing, and after that none is getting executed... :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to break the code into lines.

```
    HotKeySet('1', '_getTitle')
While 1
    Sleep(100)
WEnd
Func _getTitle()
    ConsoleWrite(WinGetTitle('[active]') & @CRLF)
    MsgBox(64, 'info', 'The title is : ' & WinGetTitle('[active]'))
    Exit (0)
EndFunc   ;==>_getTitle
```

Try it. Start the script in Scite4Autoit3. Then activate the firefox manually. Then press 1.

Comment: Mate, as you said when i pressed 1, then i got the window title as File Upload in Message Box, As i said in the script that i wrote, i used the same name it is a simple script and working for FF V 21 not for FF V 23... Please assist me mate...

Comment: One interesting thing mate, after clicking OK button for the first consoleWrite(), then i'm seeing the message like The title is C:\Users\siva.kumar\Desktop\AutoIt\AddFile.au3*, not sure mate, for the first line of the function  i can see the window title is File Upload, for the message box i'm seeing the above file path, Please let me know mate, as this is stopping my work.

Comment: Thanks for your help mate, As i said, there is dependency on FireFox Versions, now i upgraded to FF V 24 and the same script is working fine for me. Don't know how the dependency is, with out making any modifications the same script is working fine for me.... :) Please let me know mate, and sorry if i trouble you. I'm new to this AutoIt  that's what i did not able to probe a way how to deal with this concept mate... Anyways Pls let me know... :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    Opt('WinTitleMatchMode', 2) ; search substrings!
Local $winText = "File Upload"
If Not WinExists($winText) Then _output('Can''t find the window')
Local $windowHandle = WinGetHandle($winText)
If Not IsHWnd($windowHandle) Then _output('No handle')
If WinActivate($windowHandle) = 0 Then _output('Can''t activate')
Send("C:\Test\Penguins.jpg")
If Not ControlClick($windowHandle, "", "[CLASS:Button; TEXT:&Open]") Then _output('Click failed')

Func _output($txt)
    MsgBox(16, 'Error', $txt)
    Exit (0)
EndFunc   ;==>_output
```

Comment: Actually the code is working fine, if we run it individually, but when it is running with the Java code, after opening the File Upload window, it is not doing any operation and if i give the File Location manually, then i'm getting an error like Can't find the window.that we gave in Line 3 of above script, but my code and your code is working fine in Firefox 21. Is this the problem with Fire fox version 23. Please let me know. Thanks

Comment: No, I don't think it is a problem with the version itself. It could be a problem of showing another name of the window. I mean in FFv21 the window name cotains the string "File Upload". Maybe FFv23 shows something else. The would explain why WinExsits failed. Try to use Autoit Window Info on the window of FFv23 and grab the real name of the window. Or try this:

Comment: HotKeySet('1', '_getTitle')

While 1
 Sleep(100)
WEnd

Func _getTitle()
 ConsoleWrite(WinGetTitle('[active]') & @CRLF)
 MsgBox(64, 'info', 'The title is : ' & WinGetTitle('[active]'))
 Exit (0)
EndFunc   ;==>_getTitle

Comment: Mate, I'm getting AutoIt Error, like Illegal text at the end of the statement(one statement per line). don't know about this error...